# Why is Victor Creed's hair black in "X-men Origins: Wolverine"

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-origins-wolverine

In *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*, **why is Victor Creed's hair black?**

I thought that his hair was supposed to be blonde or a dirty yellow as I thought it was supposed to be in the comic. Was his hair black early in his life and does he just dye it? What explains the dark hair phenomenon? Was it in the comics?

I thought that maybe since a major part of this movie was about wolverine's mutations, maybe he got a mutation of his own that made his hair turn yellow and mutated him further into a "Sabretooth". Is there any canon info regarding his true hair color, and why it apparently changed color? Because in past movies his hair was yellow, but this movie does address a different timeline.

Comment: Wolverine is also only supposed to be 5'3", but is taller in the movies.

Comment: Blonde is female. Blond is male. *stolen french in english*

Comment: They made him Wolverine's brother and you're asking about hair colour?

Answer (score 4):

In the movie you see Victor is constantly changing, evolving, as the years go on. His hands/fingers getting more feline, his talons (er, claws) getting longer/sharper/staying out. At the same time, Creed got more aggressive, thought out his actions less. He was losing his humanity as he became more of a beast. By the time of X1, he has super long blond hair and is as mindless as a bag of bricks.

It's part of Sabretooth's ongoing mutation. Just like Wolverine. Some Mutants are born with their mutation (Changelings like Multiple Man), most get a single mutation at puberty, and some experience secondary mutations (Gambit, Beast had two, maybe three, if you count the experimental drug he took). But Sabretooth and Wolverine, whose healing factor has them physically age very little compared to what they should, continue to change. Except that Wolverine's on-going mutation is retarded by the adamantium laced into his body. His healing factor cannot get rid of the adamantium, and it has to fight against metal poisoning.

When Magneto ripped the adamantium out of wolverine in the comics, he starts to turn into a beastial form, much like Beast does. Hunched over, more muscles, flatter face, hairier, sounds dumber and harder to speak, more instinctual than logical, just like Sabretooth is.

**But no**, Comic Sabretooth, even in the Origins comic, has always been blond. The movie producers cared more about portraying the character properly than matching every single physical feature.

Comment: I'm afraid that X1 and Origins simply wasn't in the same conirnuity.

Comment: After DOFP everything is out of continuity @Mithoron but even then,  X1 and origins were considered in continuity, regardless of the massive inconsistencies.

Comment: "The movie producers cared more about portraying the character properly than matching every single physical feature." Yes, but an actress in such a situation would be required to dye her hair to match the character's. Wonder why they didn't have an actor do the same.